# What kind of group is isomorphic to a transform group of a rigid body in $R^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, trivial group $\{e\}$ is isomorphic to $Sym(X)$ where $X$ is a dot in $R^0$;

group $\{e, a\}$ is isomorphic to $Sym(X)$ where $X$ is a segment in $R^1$;

group $\{e, a, a^2\}$ is isomorphic to $Rot_\triangle$ i.e. rotations of a regular triangle in $R^2$;

Symmetric group of degree 3, or $S_3$, is isomorphic to $Sym(X)$ , where $X$ is a regular triangle in $R^2$;

$S_4$, is isomorphic to $Rot_\square$, the rotations of a cube in $R^3$;

Alternating group of degree 5, or $A_5$, is isomorphic to $Rot(X)$, the rotations of a dodecahedronin $R^3$...

So in general, which groups can be seen as some transform groups or actions, on a rigid body $X$ in $R^n$?

Comment: Is your intention to limit your question to finite groups? I notice that's what all of your examples are.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking what are the finite subgroups of the orthogonal group of $O(n)$, which is the group of invertible matrices with orthonormalized rows. In general for every finite group $G$ there exists $n$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $O(n)$, however it is a very interesting mathematical question as to which $G$ can occur for a fixed value of $n$.